# Android Custom Action Bar / Tool Bar / Tab Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I was able to get the custom navigation
[Got the custom navigation correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TATts.png) using the following link:
https://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/put-image-navigation-drawer/#sthash.2ThTJIlx.dpbs

Next I need to get this [What I needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucV0F.png) in place of action bar. But I am not able to change this [what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xygzg.png).

Code of my layout:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/navigation_imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_logo"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy_logo" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/navigationAppName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/navigation_text1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="@string/navigation_text2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Code of my Java file:

```
package com.infiso.healthapp;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import com.infiso.healthapp.adapter.DrawerItemCustomAdapter;
import com.infiso.healthapp.fragment.AboutFragment;
import com.infiso.healthapp.fragment.DashboardFragment;
import com.infiso.healthapp.fragment.MyCircleFragment;
import com.infiso.healthapp.fragment.ProfileFragment;
import com.infiso.healthapp.model.NavigationDataModel;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] mOptionMenu;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private LinearLayout mDrawerLinearLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mTitleSection;
    private Fragment mFragment = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        mOptionMenu = new String[] { getString(R.string.dashboard_fragment),
                getString(R.string.profile_fragment),
                getString(R.string.myCircle_fragment),
                getString(R.string.about_fragment)};
        NavigationDataModel[] drawerItem = new NavigationDataModel[4];

        drawerItem[0] = new NavigationDataModel(android.R.drawable.star_on, getString(R.string.dashboard_fragment),R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24);
        drawerItem[1] = new NavigationDataModel(android.R.drawable.star_on, getString(R.string.profile_fragment),R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24);
        drawerItem[2] = new NavigationDataModel(android.R.drawable.star_on, getString(R.string.myCircle_fragment),R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24);
        drawerItem[3] = new NavigationDataModel(android.R.drawable.star_on,getString(R.string.about_fragment),R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_drawer);
        /*mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getSupportActionBar()
                .getThemedContext(), R.layout.navigation_listview_item,
                mOptionMenu));*/
        DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.navigation_listview_item, drawerItem);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        initContentWithFirstFragment();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        mFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mFragment = new DashboardFragment();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mFragment = new MyCircleFragment();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mFragment = new AboutFragment();
                        break;
                }

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment).commit();

                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

                mTitleSection = mOptionMenu[position];
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);

                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinearLayout);
            }
        });
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);
        mTitleSection = getString(R.string.dashboard_fragment);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
                ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(DashboardActivity.this);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(DashboardActivity.this);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.action_settings, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                ;
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void initContentWithFirstFragment(){

        mTitleSection =getString(R.string.dashboard_fragment);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
        mFragment = new DashboardFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment).commit();
    }

}
```

Code of Adapter:

```
package com.infiso.healthapp.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.infiso.healthapp.R;
import com.infiso.healthapp.model.NavigationDataModel;

public class DrawerItemCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavigationDataModel> {

    Context mContext;
    int layoutResourceId;
    NavigationDataModel data[] = null;

    public DrawerItemCustomAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, NavigationDataModel[] data) {

        super(mContext, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItem = convertView;

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        listItem = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        ImageView imageViewIcon = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        ImageView imageViewIcon2 = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon2);

        NavigationDataModel folder = data[position];

        imageViewIcon.setImageResource(folder.icon);
        textViewName.setText(folder.name);
        imageViewIcon2.setImageResource(folder.icon2);
        return listItem;
    }
}
```

Code of Model:

```
package com.infiso.healthapp.model;

public class NavigationDataModel {

    public int icon;
    public String name;
    public int icon2;

    // Constructor.
    public NavigationDataModel(int icon, String name,int icon2) {

        this.icon = icon;
        this.name = name;
        this.icon2 = icon2;
    }
}
```

Code of list view item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code of Style:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="Theme.HealthApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">#2fad9a</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2fad9a</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.HealthApp.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.HealthApp.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.HealthApp.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
        parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_bottomsheet_dialog</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Code of AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.infiso.healthapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HealthApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignupActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SigninActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Updated Layout Design:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/custom_action_bar"></include>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/navigation_imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_logo"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy_logo" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/navigationAppName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="@string/navigation_text1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="@string/navigation_text2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Custom App Bar - List View Navigation working fine

[image]

But Frame Layout where Fragment loaded is not visible

[image]

Comment: please share style and manifest file.

Comment: Nadim.. please check now... i added Style and AndroidManifest File info here..

Comment: Added answer . please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make small change in you style.

```
<style name="Theme.HealthApp" 
 parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">#2fad9a</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2fad9a</item>
    <item 
name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Comment: "NullPointerException" is thrown because there is no action bar..

Comment: on Which line and file?

Comment: In DashboardActivity file,  getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection); line

Comment: Comment it.From my code you can hide default Action bar so you can draw your custom action bar. So comment it.

Comment: ok i will check now Nadim.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nadim.. if i draw a custom action bar, how to add hamburger icon navigation functionality to it? or will it be added automatically in custom action bar like in default action bar? or will the navigation icon be gone in custom?

Comment: You need to design each and every thing on layout and you can include it in any layout.

Comment: You are using Darwer layout for Navigation and you can open it and closed it easily you have to just deisgn appbar and include appbar on top each activity layout.

Comment: Nadim.. i tried to add custom view for action/app bar.. but its not working.. can you please show me in code, how to add it? i used ActionBar actionBar= getActionBar(); Then actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.customActionLayout); or do i need to add appbar layout inside Coordinator layout or some other layout?

Comment: Nadim.. i am able to get the custom app bar to show.. but now FrameLayout is not visible.. Can you please check? I will add in the code and screenshot

Comment: image links: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvxjd.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecSyU.png

Comment: Update code for that

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nadim.. I got what I wanted.. Thanks again for your guidance...

Comment: if you really think i helped you then you can Up Vote and Accept my answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Style **DarkActionBar** to **NoActionBar**

**From :**

```
    <style name="Theme.HealthApp" 
 parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">#2fad9a</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2fad9a</item>
    <item 
name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

**To :**

```
<style name="Theme.HealthApp" 
 parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">#2fad9a</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2fad9a</item>
    <item 
name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```